Openness of the set of operators with finite dimensional kernel and being homeomorphism on one complement of kernel
Let $E$, $F$ be normed spaces (not necessarily Banach), $u$ a continuous linear mapping of $E$ into $F$, such that $N=\ker u$ is finite dimensional, and there exists a topological complement $M$ of $N$ such that the restriction of $u$ to $M$ is a homeomorphism onto $u(M)=u(E)$. Let $w$ be a continuous linear mapping of $E$ into $F$; show that if $||w||$ is small enough, and $f=u+w$, then $\ker f$ has dimension at most equal to the dimension of $\ker u$, and there is a closed topological complement $P$ of $\ker f$, such that the restriction of $f$ to $P$ is a homeomorphism onto $f(P)=f(E)$.

The problem comes with a hint to use results from the previous problem, which says that for $u$ a linear homeomorphism of $E$ onto $u(E)\subset F$, let $v:u(E)\rightarrow E$ be the inverse of $u$, and $m=||v||$. Suppose $w$ is a continuous linear mapping of $E$ into $F$ with $||w||<{1\over m}$ and $f=u+v$. Then $f$ is a homeomorphism of $E$ onto $f(E)$. Furthermore, for any $y_0\in u(E)$ such that $||y_0||=1$, there exists $y\in f(E)$ such that $||y-y_0||\le m||w||$; conversely for any $y\in f(E)$ with $||y||=1$ there is $y_0\in u(E)$ such that $||y-y_0||\le {m||w||\over 1-m||w||}$.
The results in the hint are straightforward to prove, and letting $v:u(M)\rightarrow M$ be the inverse of $u\restriction M$, and $m=||v||$, when $||w||<{1\over m}$, $f\restriction M$ is a homeomorphism onto $f(M)$. Consider $(f\restriction M)^{-1}(w(N)\cap f(M))$ with basis $\{x_i\}_{1\le i\le l}$ and $w(y_i)=f(x_i)$, then $\ker f=\text{span}(\{x_i-y_i\}_{1\le i\le l})\oplus\ker w\restriction N$, which has dimension at most $\dim N$. I have also shown that $\ker f$ has a topological complement $M\oplus Q$ where $Q$ is the complement of $\text{span}(\{y_i\}_{1\le i\le l})\oplus\ker w\restriction N$ in $N$.
Yet I cannot show $f$ is a homeomorphism of $M\oplus Q$ onto $f(M\oplus Q)$. It turns out it's necessary and sufficient to show $f(M)$ is closed in $f(E)$, but I have no idea how to proceed. Also I don't know how to use the results in the hint after 'furthermore'. Any help would be appreciated.
